# Set a list in a variable in subquery - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My problem is the following, I want set a list of ID in a variable, then use this variable in a subquery. The problem is that WorkBench (my GUI) return the following error : "subquery returning multiple rows". It seems to me that's what I want.

 Please explain me where I am wrong.

This is my query :

```
set @listID := (select ID_VOIE as ID from voies
    where ORIGINE = 'XXX'
    group by CODE_INSEE, CODE_VOIE
    having count(*) > 1);

select substring(v.CODE_INSEE,1,2), count(*) from voies v
    where v.ID_VOIE in (@listID)
    group by substring(vs.CODE_INSEE,1,2);
```

The thing is I'm blocked with the "group by", I want do a groupd by after a first group by, that's why I can't (or at least i didn't find a way) write the request with a single WHERE clause.

The thing is I know that I can put the whole request directly in my subquery instead of using variable but :

- It can let me use this trick in another requests that needed this behaviour (DRY concept !)
- I'm not sure but the subquery will be executed in each turn of my loop, and that will be very inefficient

So I seek 2 possible ways : a way that let me use a list in a variable in a subquery OR a way that let me use "group by" twice in a single query.

Thanks you in advance for your answers (oh and sorry for my english, this is not my maternal language).

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could be a little more explicit about "poor design".

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need that variable for something else, you should be able to skip it entirely as follows:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(v.CODE_INSEE,1,2),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    voies v
WHERE
    v.ID_VOIE in
    (SELECT
         ID_VOIE as ID
     FROM
         voies
     WHERE
         ORIGINE = 'XXX'
     GROUP BY
         CODE_INSEE,
         CODE_VOIE
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(vs.CODE_INSEE,1,2);
```

As you say, the subquery will be executed for all rows. To avoid that, a variable would be best, but MySQL doesn't support table variables. Instead, you can use a temporary table:

```
IF EXISTS DROP TABLE myTempTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable (ID_VOIE int); -- I don't know the datatype
INSERT INTO myTempTable (ID_VOIE)
SELECT DISTINCT -- using distinct so I can join instead of use IN.
    ID_VOIE as ID from voies
WHERE
    ORIGINE = 'XXX'
GROUP BY
    CODE_INSEE, CODE_VOIE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And now you can do this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(v.CODE_INSEE,1,2), COUNT(*)
FROM
   voies v
   JOIN myTempTable tt ON
       v.ID_VOIE = tt.ID_VOIE
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(vs.CODE_INSEE,1,2);
```

Comment: That's what I meant with "The thing is I know that I can put the whole request directly in my subquery instead of using variable".
Here i didn't put more tha necessary but i need multiples times this result.

Anyway Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Final Edit : It seems the request works and give me what i wanted. Thx for all !
Just a single thing: I had to erase the 3IF" statement because WorkBench told me "invalid input at this position".

Comment: Any time you find DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query, you can be ninety percent certain that something's wrong somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I originally had a typo there, I'd accidently put "IF EXIST" rather than "IF EXISTS".

Comment: It does seem a little odd @Strawberry. But given that we also have a `HAVING` I can at least imagine cases where this would be correct, but not having any idea what the data actually represents, it's hard to say!

Comment: Yes, here the "distinct" isn't useful, i removed it without notification here. (and yes the schema of my db is awful but i have to deal with, it's not mine :( )

Comment: That's good and will make the query quicker. I had assumed it was necessary because you had two items in the group by of the "sub query" and had commented that when attempting the combine the queries you'd run into difficulties on account of grouping. From what I can see of the data structure it is appears to be possible for an `id_voie` to appear more than once in the first data set, and if that happens it would distort the overall query. Anyway, you'll know the data better, and if you can do without the `DISTINCT` then all the better!